# Google Analytics propagate source

Tags: javascript, php, google-analytics

I am using Google tag Manager and Google Analytics.

I have a link on my yelp page like `example.com/?utm_source=Yelp`.

What I want is to be able to track that source even if the user clicks on a different link on my website, say to example.com/new-article.

So if a user fills out a form on that page, I know the user came from Yelp.

Summary:

A customer goes from Yelp to example.com then clicks another link.  How can I still know that the user came from Yelp?

One strategy is I can append utm_source=$_GET['utm_source'] on all links on my page, but I assume google analytics or google tag manager has already solved that problem.  I'm having trouble finding information on this.

Comment: I think you can check the flow of traffic using GA's Behavior Flow under the Behavior tab.

Answer (score 0):

Source is a session-level dimension, so if a user comes to your site with a `utm_source` param in the URL, that source dimension will be applied to all hits (pageviews, events, etc.) in the session.

In other words, you don't need to do anything special to make this work.

Comment: I see.  Good to know.  I have a form on the second page where we grab the source from the utm variable and put it in a hidden variable.  Is it possible to populate that hidden input using Google tag manager?

Comment: I'm saying you don't need that input at all as long as these hits are all part of the same session.

Comment: I understand that.   The form on page 2 submits to our crm. That form has a hidden input for referrer.  Before I was getting it from the url.  Now I'm curious how to fetch it from the GA session.

Comment: I see, since you're talking about CRM data and not GA data, then I suppose yes, you should continue to send it to the CRM if that's data you care about. There isn't a way to query data about the current session until after the session has been processed by GA on the back end, so that wouldn't work for your case.